# How to video out java through DVI/HDMI?

Tags: java, processing, visualizer, hdmi

For a project I have to create a music visualizer in java (I've decided on using www.processing.org to create the visuals) and then output it using DVI/HDMI to a spartan-6 board. I haven't been able to find much out there.

I'm fairly early in the project so I could change from processing if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, the type of screen or whether you use VGA, DVI or HDMI makes no difference to Java. You need to configure these devices in the OS and Java will use them.

Comment: So just full screen the java app and then use the computer's video out?